# Exclude categories from homepage but not from sidebar

Tags: categories

I would like to exclude categories from my homepage, but I want them to still display in the sidebar shown on the homepage, how can I do that?

At the moment my code excludes from both the content area and the sidebar, and I am putting the code in the functions.php file:

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {    
        $query->set( 'cat', '-5, -34' );
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to alter the loop on the homepage.
Set it up in your index.php:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
query_posts( 'cat=-5,-34' );
}
```

and you should be good to go.